# JBoss 7.2: Active Sessions Count

Tags: session, jboss7.x, jmx

How can I get the number of active session counts at the Jboss AS 7.2 (all sessions, not at single war)? I looked deeply for a MXBean that could give me that information but I didn't find one. There are a lot of information about that, but just for older versions. This seens to be an easy thing to do, but it's been very difficult to find an answer.

JMX is not a must if I can get this programatically by another way. I just cant modify the older projects to add listeners to check for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after some digging I found an way using JBoss CLI (just google a little about it and the special syntax called Detyped Management Model). With that in mind just call this command at the CLI:

`/deployment=<YOUR-EAR-NAME>.ear/subdeployment=<YOUR-WAR-NAME>.war/subsystem=\"web\"/:read-attribute(name=active-sessions)`

With that you can know the connected users for that specific war. This can be tunned with different ways to look for all wars, so just play with it. There's an API to do that programatically too.

Comment: can u please tell me how to call that command exactly? @israel

Comment: @MaheshVarma, to use it execute the <yourdir>/bin/jboss-cli.sh. Here are some examples: [JBoss CLI Recipes](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/CLI+Recipes?_sscc=t). Don't forget to pass your IP as argument (first example shows that).

Comment: Thanks! I was able to see the active sessions. but if the user closes the browser window then it is also considering as an active session. how to filter this? I am trying to get the list of online users who are using our web app at currently. Please help @IsraelFonseca

Comment: @MaheshVarma, by default sessions are not destroyed when the user simply closes the browser window, and I think that you shouldn't the CURRENT users as metric. I think that the session in an JSF environment by default have 10 min duration, this will show you how many people were online in the last 10 min. If you really want that, you will have to implement some servlet filters, and crazy workarounds to see who is truly on at an specific momment.

Comment: @MaheshVarma you could use a websocket and count the number of open sockets - they close when the user shuts the browser

Comment: @TomChamberlain Thaks